# PHP three SQL select statement

Tags: php, sql

i have one database with three tables and i am trying to get some information for all the tables

`activities` -> contains events/ acivities and uses the userIds of another table to identify the row.

`teams` -> contains a listing of teams (including the id stored in activities) and the attributed assigned to each team such as name away colors etc.

`facilities` -> contain list of all the facilities activities can be booked at

I would like to create a select statement that uses the `activities` table to get the home and away teams then look up the teams names (not ids which is stored in the activities database) and get the name of the `facility`.

i have used the following sql

```
$select = "SELECT *, teams.name 
            FROM activities, teams 
            WHERE (SELECT * 
                    FROM teams 
                    WHERE teams.id=activities.teamIdAway) activities.status=(:s) 
                AND activities.dateStart >= (:start) 
                AND activities.dateEnd <= (:end) 
                AND activities.facilityId=(:f)";
```

Comment: Please fix your query so it uses explicit joins.

Comment: How is `facilities` related to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two join with the `teams` table, one for the home team, another for the away team.

```
SELECT f.name, ht.name AS hometeam, at.name AS awayteam
FROM facilities AS f
JOIN activities AS a ON a.facilityId = :f
JOIN teams AS at ON at.id = a.teamIdAway
JOIN teams AS ht ON ht.id = a.teamIdHome
WHERE a.dateStart >= :start
AND a.dateEnd <= :end
AND a.status = :s
```

Comment: should activities read a.dateStart i keep getting an error which indicates activities.dateStart does not exist

Comment: If i adjust activities.dateStart to a.dateStart i yeild no results

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with some sample data?